# Retrieve connection string to Azure storage in ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to retrieve the connection string to an Azure storage account, that is defined in the config.json file this way (after adding it using the solution explorer option "Add connected service..."):

```
"MicrosoftAzureStorage": {
    "almacen_AzureStorageConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=almacen;AccountKey=pLrQwW......"
```

}

Attending to the Microsoft instructions (that worked well with MVC 5) you do this to retrieve the connection string:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("almacen_AzureStorageConnectionString"));
```

but CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(...) returns always null.
When debugged and tried in an Inmediate window I get this output for the call:

```
?CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("almacen_AzureStorageConnectionString")
Exception thrown: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" in mscorlib.dll
Getting "almacen_AzureStorageConnectionString" from ServiceRuntime: FAIL.
Getting "almacen_AzureStorageConnectionString" from ConfigurationManager: FAIL.
```

I'm using the RC1 version and I've included references to Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration and Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json packages.

**EDIT**

For the comments below I assume that isn't possible for CloudConfigurationManager to get the connection string from config.json... So, **what is the correct procedure to retrieve the connection string to an azure storage from the config.json in the way it's left by the "Add connected service..." dialog?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit late but since I made this question someone thought that it was wiseful to implement an easier way to retrieve a connection string. So I'll answer my own question, because now you can do:

```
string conn = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ExampleConnection");
```

in the ConfigureServices method if you previously have declared it this way on your appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ExampleConnection": "blah,blah..."
},
```

NOTE: You have to add a reference to Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration for this static method to work.

Answer (score 2):

The CloudConfigurationManager doesn't understand config.json. You're using 2 different configuration systems.

Comment: So I have to stick to ConfigurationManager then?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you using the new config system?

Comment: With the new configuration system I have to create two classes and register a middleware just to pass one single configuration parameter... (to mimic the structure of the config.json file the way it's left by the "Add connected service..." option) I don't like very much, but it seems that's the way with everything in ASP.NET 5, all dependency injection, miriad of interfaces... Is there any other option?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you show me with a code sample?

Comment: I mean that the "Add connected service..." option in the Solution Explorer creates a key in the config.json called "MicrosoftAzureStorage", wich in turn has another key called "mystoragename_AzureStorageConnectionString" who's value is the actual connection string. To retrieve it with the IOptions interface I have to create two POCOs to mimic this structure, register them on the pipeline and then inject them on the controllers. All this just to read one setting! There's a simpler way or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

David did answer your question, hahaha. But, yeah, IMHO all this DI is crazy for small projects, but it's the new normal. (This is sort of answered in a few different spots, with the various betas it has changed a little) With RC1 Here's what I did:

The connection string in the `settings.json`,

```
"MicrosoftAzureStorage": {
    "xxxxxx_AzureStorageConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxx;AccountKey=SuperSecretKey==;BlobEndpoint=https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/"
}
```

Created a class called `AzureSettings`

```
public class AzureSettings
{
    public string xxxxxx_AzureStorageConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Added it in `ConfigureServices` in the Startup.cs, I put it in after `AddMvc()`

```
services.Configure<AzureSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftAzureStorage"))
```

Then in my controller

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private string _AzureConnectionString;

    public ImagesController(IOptions<AzureSettings> settings)
    {
        _AzureConnectionString = settings.Value.xxxxxx_AzureStorageConnectionString;
    }
```

And then this part should look familiar ;)

```
// GET: /<controller>/
public IActionResult Index()
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    _AzureConnectionString);

    // Create a blob client.
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Do stuff

    return View();
    }
 }
```